# xcode - viewForAnnotation slow (over 3k Annotations) ... normal?

Tags: xcode, json, annotations, mapkit, android-mapview

Hy Guys!

I have about 3-4k Annotations in my MySQL, receive them via assynchronous request... only showing the Annotations is ok, but i want that the user can select a highlighted Annotation to go to DetailView (is not implemented yet, it´s only for testing)...

Only showing the Annotations is ok, takes only a few seconds (without the "viewForAnnotation" Method) ... but: with this Method it takes about 1 Minute that it shows all Annotations and give me the possibility of using my "showDetails" Button.

OR: is my code wrong (i´m completely new in Xcode)... looks like my code creates a complete new view for every annotation, right?

If my Code is complete Nonsense tell it to me and i have to try it again from scratch, but maybe i can use the Code and change somethings. :-)

thx 4 help
Gerhard

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
/*{
   IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
}*/
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loadingView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pois;
@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()
@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    _mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self loadPoiData];
    [self zoomToUserLocation:self.mapView.userLocation];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [self zoomToUserLocation:self.mapView.userLocation];
}

- (void)zoomToUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (!userLocation)
        return;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2);
    region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];   
}

- (void)loadPoiData
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL/AppFiles/poidrive.php"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if(jsonData != nil)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        _pois = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }

    _loadingView.hidden = YES;

    for (NSDictionary *annotations in _pois)
    {
        location.latitude = [annotations[@"POI_LAT"] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = [annotations[@"POI_LONG"] doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude);

        MKPointAnnotation *point = [MKPointAnnotation new];

        point.coordinate = coords;
        point.title = [annotations objectForKey:@"POI_NAME"];
        point.subtitle = [annotations objectForKey:@"POI_ID"];

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
// if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

// try to dequeue an existing pin view first
static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] ;
pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
NSLog(@"test");

UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

//UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"]];
//pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;

return pinView;
}

-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@",((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you are creating a new view on every call to `viewForAnnotation`. Take a look at the Apple docs about [reusing annotation views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW1) especially [dequeueing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier%3a).

Comment: ok thx, i'll take a closer look at it (or two :) )

will then the first loading (to show everything on the map) be faster?

or can i only speed it up by limit the number of annotations?